# Are folders counted as items in Sharepoint Document Libraries?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, directory, document-library

In Sharepoint on the All Site Content screen, it lists my SharePoint Document Library with a numeric row containing "Items".

Do these "Items" include "folders and docuemnts" or just "folders"?

Answer (score 0):

Folders are not counted as items.

Comment: I think you're wrong. I think it does count folders as Items. I just wrote a program that counted the number of files I uploaded, and also counted the number of folders I created, and they add up to be the number in the Items column.

Comment: I'm looking at mine right now, its a knowledgebase with 155 articles. I just added a folder, and it is showing 155 items.

Comment: @DanBig What version of SharePoint are you using? (that could be the difference)

Comment: I'm using MOSS 2007

Comment: ...or maybe it has to do with How the Item was created...I'm using web services to create the list, and the folders.  And I'm using REST to upload the files...

Comment: Okay, I'm using SharePoint Foundation 2010, that explains some of the differnce.

Comment: Could be, i'm not familiar enough with 2010.

Comment: Count in View all Items adds the count of Folders as well, atleast in SP 2010 it does for sure.